# Which Dart operators are allowed to be overloaded?

Tags: dart

For illustration purposes, I want to overload unary prefix and postfix `--` operators.  However, the editor (VSCode) gives me a red wavy line as follows. Adding `@override` does not help as well.

[image]

I cannot find a list of overloadable operators in Dart. Is there such a list available?

## Example

```
import 'dart:math';

class Point {
  double _x, _y;
  Point(this._x, this._y);
  Point.Origin()
      : _x = 0,
        _y = 0;

  double DistanceTo(Point other) {
    var dx = x - other.x;
    var dy = y - other.y;
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  }

  double get x => _x;
  double get y => _y;

  set x(double _) => _x = _;
  set y(double _) => _y = _;

  Point operator -() => Point(-x, -y);
  //Point operator -(p) => Point(--x,--y)  ;
  
  @override
  Point  operator --() => Point(x-1,y-1);

  @override
  Point operator +() => this;

  //Point operator +(double r) => Point(x+r,y+r);
  Point operator +(Point r) => Point(x + r.x, y + r.y);
}
```

Comment: see my answer let me know if you like it ;)

Comment: The list of *overridable* (Dart does not support overloading) operators is listed in the Dart Language Tour, but it's not labeled as such (overridable operators are operators that can exist as instance methods): https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#_operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the full list of supported operators listed [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf)

page 30:

> **The following names are allowed for user-defined operators: ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘<=’,
> ‘>=’, ‘==’, ‘-’, ‘+’, ‘/’, ‘˜/’, ‘*’, ‘%’, ‘|’, ‘ˆ’, ‘&’, ‘<<’, ‘>>’, ‘>>>’, ‘[]=’, ‘[]’, ‘˜’.**

So I am afraid that you cannot override -- or ++ operator.

---

#### If you are only interested into a quick way to decrement or increment your point

I found a little hack for you if you are okay to lose some operators:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

class Point {
  double x, y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);
  Point.origin()
      : x = 0,
        y = 0;

  double distanceTo(Point other) {
    var dx = x - other.x;
    var dy = y - other.y;
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  }

  Point operator -(Point r) => Point(x-r.x, x-r.y);
  Point operator +(Point r) => Point(x + r.x, y + r.y);

  // bye bye shift operations
  Point operator >>(Point r)=> Point(x-1, y-1);
  Point operator <<(Point r)=> Point(x+1, y+1);

  @override toString() {
    return "Point ($x,$y)";
  }
}
```

And use this way:

```dart
Point a = new Point(3,5);
a>>=(a); // a(x--,y--);
print(a);
a<<=(a); // a(x++,y++);
print(a);
```

Output:

```
I/flutter (10464): Point (2.0,4.0)
I/flutter (10464): Point (3.0,5.0)
```

PS: no need for getters and setters in Dart ;)

Edit: For your last question in comment:

```dart
Point operator +(Point r) => Point(x, y);
```

And use like:

```dart
a+(a);
```

Note that for minus you will not need to provide an argument (arity is 0 means 0 arg)

> It is a compile-time error if the arity of a user-declared operator with one of the names: ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘<=’, ‘>=’, ‘==’, ‘-’, **‘+’**, [...] **is not 1**. **It is a compile-time error if the arity of the user-declared operator ‘-’ is not 0 or 1**.

Comment: Overloading `>>` and `<<` as a substitute for `--` and `++` provides no advantage to providing `increment` and `decrement` methods instead.  And, unlike using `>>` and `<<`, `increment` and `decrement` would be unambiguous.

Comment: Thats true, I would also rather have `.inc()` and `.dec()` methods, but everyone is different ;)

Comment: Hence why I went for abusing the binary operator. You cannot perform shift operations on double anyways. I found the page in the manual that tells about your question with just a + and no argument: it is not possible.